# How to get the last time the host machine rebooted from inside the docker container?

Tags: docker

`last reboot` works in a linux machine

```
$ last reboot
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-142-gener Thu May 11 16:31   still running
...

wtmp begins Fri May  5 19:27:11 2023
```

Inside a container, it doesn't (returns empty)

```
# last reboot

wtmp begins Mon Mar 27 09:55:22 2023
```

Is there a way to know the uptime/last-reboot of the host machine from inside a container?

Comment: on most distributions, just `uptime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**last**(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/last) looks in the file `/var/log/wtmp` for this information.  Since the container has its own isolated filesystem, it can't see the host's `wtmp` file, and this information is not accessible.

[**procinfo**(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/procinfo) includes this information from the artificial `/proc` filesystem.  Since this is kernel-level data you should be able to read it.

More specifically, [**proc**(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) documents that `/proc/uptime` contains the time the system has been running in seconds.  You can subtract that from the current time to find the last time the system has been rebooted.

```bash
cat /proc/uptime
675814.56 1014657.89
```

This fragment should work on most Linux environments (the `date -d` option is not specified by POSIX, but this works in both `busybox` and `ubuntu` containers):

```bash
#!/bin/sh
now=$(date +%s)
uptime=$(cut -d. -f1 /proc/uptime) # cut on the decimal point, so in whole seconds
boot_time=$(("$now" - "$uptime"))
date -d "$boot_time"
```

Note though, if your Docker is running in a virtual machine (including Docker Desktop on all platforms) this returns the boot time of the VM and not of the containing host.

Answer (score 0):

`last` reads the boot times from `/var/log/wtmp`, so if you map that file into the container, it'll show the boot times of the host. Like this

```
docker run --rm -v /var/log/wtmp:/var/log/wtmp:ro debian last reboot
```